# An error when I try to force file downloading with php

Tags: php, http-headers

I try the simple php script to force file downloading from server:

```
$file = '13.zip';
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$file);
header("Content-type: application/zip");
readfile($file);
```

The file downloads but if I try to open it on my local machine I get the error message "The Compresed (zipped) Folder C:/.../13.zip is invalid" and zip has only 1 KB. What's wrong?

Comment: Why are we posting comments instead of answers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
<?php

    $file = "13.zip";

    $file_name = basename($file);

    header("Content-Type: application/zip");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file_name");
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file)); //added this line

    readfile($file);
?>
```

Comment: Delete your `error_log` and try again, they might be old errors. @stckvrw